# Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard cannot be found while trying to install usb_network_gate on WSL2

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install usb network gate on ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 with this kernel version installed on :

```
root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-N9UN2H3 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard #2 SMP Tue Jun 30 14:38:02 CEST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

unfortunately it ends wit this error that I don't know how to fix :

Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard cannot be found

```
root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# dpkg -i usb_network_gate_x64.deb
(Reading database ... 352800 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack usb_network_gate_x64.deb ...
Unpacking eveusb (9.1.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eveusb:
eveusb depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4.8.1); however:
Package libqt4-dbus is not installed.
eveusb depends on libqt4-svg (>= 4.8.1); however:
Package libqt4-svg is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package eveusb (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
eveusb

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# apt install libqt4-dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
eveusb : Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
libqt4-dbus : Depends: qdbus (= 5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libjpeg62 libllvm9:i386 libtirpc-common libtirpc3
linux-headers-5.4.0-39 linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libqt4-dbus libqt4-svg qdbus
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libqt4-dbus libqt4-svg qdbus
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 387 kB of archives.
After this operation, 947 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal/main amd64 qdbus amd64 5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7 [99.9 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libqt4-dbus amd64 5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7 [76.0 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libqt4-svg amd64 5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7 [211 kB]
Fetched 387 kB in 1s (502 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package qdbus.
(Reading database ... 352926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qdbus_5%3a4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qdbus (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt4-dbus:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libqt4-dbus_5%3a4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-dbus:amd64 (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt4-svg:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libqt4-svg_5%3a4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-svg:amd64 (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Setting up libqt4-svg:amd64 (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Setting up qdbus (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Setting up libqt4-dbus:amd64 (5:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu4rock7) ...
Setting up eveusb (9.1.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst configure
Unable to identify user running this installation.
Please add users manually to the 'eveusb' group so they can control the daemon u
sing GUI and console utilities.
Examples:
gpasswd -a eveusb
groupmod --add-user eveusb # SUSE
usermod --append --groups eveusb
usermod --add-to-group eveusb # SUSE
Synchronizing state of eveusb.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd
/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable eveusb

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/eveusb/1.0.0/source ->
/usr/src/eveusb-1.0.0

DKMS: add completed.
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard cannot be fou
nd.
Please install the linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 549, in
make_all()
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 528, in make_all
process_module(True)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 268, in process_module
check_call([dkms, action] + mod_ver)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 30, in check_call
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dkms', 'build', '-m', 'eveusb', '-v',
'1.0.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1
dpkg: error processing package eveusb (--configure):
installed eveusb package post-installation script subprocess returned error exi
t status 1
/bin/df: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc: Too many levels of symbolic links
Processing t
riggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
eveusb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# dpkg -i usb_network_gate_x64.deb
(Reading database ... 352951 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack usb_network_gate_x64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.prerm upgrade 9.1.0
Synchronizing state of eveusb.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable eveusb
Deleting module version: 1.0.0
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
groupdel: group 'eveusb' does not exist
Unpacking eveusb (9.1.0) over (9.1.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postrm upgrade 9.1.0
Setting up eveusb (9.1.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst configure
Unable to identify user running this installation.
Please add users manually to the 'eveusb' group so they can control the daemon using GUI and console utilities.
Examples:
gpasswd -a eveusb
groupmod --add-user eveusb # SUSE
usermod --append --groups eveusb
usermod --add-to-group eveusb # SUSE
Synchronizing state of eveusb.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable eveusb

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/eveusb/1.0.0/source ->
/usr/src/eveusb-1.0.0

DKMS: add completed.
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 549, in
make_all()
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 528, in make_all
process_module(True)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 268, in process_module
check_call([dkms, action] + mod_ver)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 30, in check_call
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dkms', 'build', '-m', 'eveusb', '-v', '1.0.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1
dpkg: error processing package eveusb (--install):
installed eveusb package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
eveusb

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-N9UN2H3 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard #2 SMP Tue Jun 30 14:38:02 CEST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# apt install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0.45.49).
linux-headers-generic set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libjpeg62 libllvm9:i386 libtirpc-common libtirpc3
linux-headers-5.4.0-39 linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up eveusb (9.1.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst configure
Unable to identify user running this installation.
Please add users manually to the 'eveusb' group so they can control the daemon u
sing GUI and console utilities.
Examples:
gpasswd -a eveusb
groupmod --add-user eveusb # SUSE
usermod --append --groups eveusb
usermod --add-to-group eveusb # SUSE
Synchronizing state of eveusb.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd
/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable eveusb
Deleting module version: 1.0.0
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/eveusb/1.0.0/source ->
/usr/src/eveusb-1.0.0

DKMS: add completed.
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard cannot be fou
nd.
Please install the linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 549, in
make_all()
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 528, in make_all
process_module(True)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 268, in process_module
check_call([dkms, action] + mod_ver)
File "/var/lib/dpkg/info/eveusb.postinst", line 30, in check_call
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dkms', 'build', '-m', 'eveusb', '-v',
'1.0.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1
dpkg: error processing package eveusb (--configure):
installed eveusb package post-installation script subprocess returned error exi
t status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
eveusb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.8.0-rc3-microsoft-standard'
```

any help ?

Comment: Try to install this `libqt4-dbus` or check from [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libqt4-dbus)

Answer (score 1):

USB Network Gate apparently requires a kernel extension of some sort.  On a standard Debian or Ubuntu installation, such an extension can be added by providing source and using the DKMS system to build kernel modules for the appropriate kernel.  However, doing so requires the kernel headers for the appropriate kernel, which are normally shipped in a package by the distribution.

However, with WSL, the kernel used is not the one shipped by the distribution, but a specific one shipped by Microsoft.  While the kernel does support modules, it isn't compiled to use any, and as such, Microsoft doesn't ship packages for any kernel headers (although the [source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel)).  Your distro isn't responsible for Microsoft's kernel, so they also don't ship any headers for it.

As a result, it isn't really possible to build kernel modules for WSL.  If you want to use something that requires kernel modules, you'll need a real Linux system, either in a VM or on real hardware.

Comment: so. Can I use a real linux system using to compile the WSL2 microsoft kernel with the modules ?

Comment: You can technically compile the modules with the kernel source code in WSL, but you'll have to do it by hand.  I assume it's possible to load them, but I don't know for certain.  You cannot replace Microsof't's kernel with WSL 2, so compiling a new kernel itself won't help.  In general, if you're not already familiar with how to do this, I strongly recommend using a real Linux system and not trying to do it on WSL.